# Why does `systemd-nspawn -n` network namespace not show in `ip netns list`?

Tags: iproute, namespace, network-namespaces, systemd-nspawn

**tl;dr** Linux has namespaces, in particular, `network namespaces`. It seems the namespace supposedly created via the `-n` flag when running `systemd-nspwawn` does not show up when employing `ip netns list` (neither in the host nor in the supposedly created namespace). It is either `systemd-nspawn` or `ip netns` not actually dealing with Linux namespaces (something I thought to be this: https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index)?

**longer story:**
I use the following command to run a "light-weight container" of Arch Linux from within my Arch Linux:

```
systemd-nspawn -nbUD /mntpointArchLinuxSysFs
```

the data at `/mntpointArchLinuxSysFs` has been bootstrapped, and "runs/boots" well. The man [systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) tells me that the `-n` options-flag means:

> `-n`, `--network-veth`
>
> Create a virtual Ethernet link ("`veth`") between host and container. The host side of the Ethernet link will be available as a
>   network interface named after the container's name (as specified with
>   `--machine=`), prefixed with "`ve-`". The container side of the Ethernet link will be named "`host0`". The `--network-veth` option implies
>   `--private-network`.

In turn, the implied `--private-network` is explained thus

> `--private-network`
>
> ```
> Disconnect networking of the container from the host. This makes all network interfaces unavailable in the container, with the
> ```
>
> exception of the loopback device and those specified with
>   `--network-interface=` and configured with `--network-veth`. If this option is specified, the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability will be added to the
>   set of capabilities the container retains. The latter may be disabled
>   by using `--drop-capability=`. If this option is not specified (or
>   implied by one of the options listed below), the container will have
>   full access to the host network.

which seems to be a feat which is achieved via *Linux namespaces*, in particular *Linux network namespaces*, this that the started processes (i.e. the `init` of the container at `/mntpointArchLinuxSysFs/bin/init` and all child processes are in a different network namespace, i.e. are `--private-network` and only have the `veth` (virtual ethernet pair) as a remaining connection to the `host` namespace/system.

Using [lsns](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsns.8.html) shows that indeed `systemd-nspawn` created a namespace

```
root@host$> lsns | grep net
4026531992 net       183     1 root     /sbin/init
4026532332 net         1   824 rtkit    /usr/lib/rtkit-daemon
4026532406 net         7  4697 vu-mnt-0 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

However `ip netns list` does refuse to "play along":

```
root@host$> ip netns list
root@host$>
```

Then is I for the sake of understanding create a dummy namespace via `ip netns` like this

```
root@host$> ip netns add dummy_netns
root@host$> ip netns list
dummy_netns
root@host$>
```

A network namespace is displayed, however, misses ironically in the `lsns`.

In conclusion, it seems to be unclear how the term "network namespace" is used in `systemd-nspawn`, `ip netns` as my test seem to suggest they might not really be the same thing? Maybe the term is ambiguous?

**update**

this part of the `systemd-nspawn` man page suggest imho, however that indeed both `iproute` and `systemd-nspawn` refer to the same thing in terms of **network namespaces**.

> `--network-namespace-path=`
>              Takes the path to a file representing a kernel network namespace
>              that the container shall run in. The specified path should refer to
>              a (possibly bind-mounted) network namespace file, as exposed by the
>              kernel below `/proc/$PID/ns/net`. This makes the container enter the
>              given network namespace. One of the typical use cases is to give a
>              network namespace under `/run/netns` created by `ip-netns(8)`, for
>              example, `--network-namespace-path=/run/netns/foo`. Note that this
>              option cannot be used together with other network-related options,
>              such as --private-network or --network-interface=.

Even though the last part stating that it cannot be used with the `--private-network` option again seems to suggest some sort of distincion. what is going on here?

Comment: Notice the network namespace created by `ip` and `systemd-nspawn` is different, the former creates one and bind mount it to /run/ns, so even if no process is in that namespace, it's still available, and former possibly only list such bind-mounted namespace under /run/ns. But lsns list namespace simply by searching the whole /proc, all the namespace listed has some process in it. I suggest you create a namespace using `ip` then check by `lsns`. I guess you will not see it.

Answer (score 2):

Both `systemd-nspawn` and `ip-netns` use namespaces, specifically network namespaces. The difference, as explained in the [ip-netns manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html), is that `ip-netns` deals with **named** network namespaces.

> By convention a named network namespace is an object at `/var/run/netns/NAME` that can be opened. The file descriptor resulting from opening `/var/run/netns/NAME` refers to the specified network namespace. Holding that file descriptor open keeps the network namespace alive.

## Anonymous network namespaces

The [namespaces(7) manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) explains that in general, a namespace is an abstraction associated with the lifetime of the processes in it:

> Each process has a `/proc/[pid]/ns/` subdirectory containing one entry for each namespace that supports being manipulated by `setns(2)` ... Opening one of the files in this directory (or a file that is bind mounted to one of these files) returns a file handle for the corresponding namespace of the process specified by pid. As long as this file descriptor remains open, the namespace will remain alive, even if all processes in the namespace terminate.

On my system, the most recently launched `systemd` process (`pgrep -f -n systemd\$`) is the init process of a container started using the default `systemd-nspawn@.service` template unit, which enables `--network-veth` and thus `--private-network` (it also adds `--private-users`). This command shows that the container's anonymous network namespace is different to the root network namespace, and owned by the container's root user:

```
# ls -l /proc/1/ns/net /proc/$(pgrep -f -n systemd\$)/ns/net
lrwxrwxrwx 0 root           /proc/1/ns/net -> net:[4026532008]
lrwxrwxrwx 0 vu-container-0 /proc/700/ns/net -> net:[4026532656]
```

This anonymous network namespace disappears when the container is terminated. However, if I want to make it a named network namespace that can be managed with `ip-netns` during the life of the container, I can bind mount it under `/run/netns`:

```
# mount --bind /proc/$(pgrep -f -n systemd\$)/ns/net /run/netns/container
# ip netns list
container (id: 1)
```

## Creating named network namespaces with systemd

You've also pointed out `systemd-nspawn`'s `--network-namespace-path` option, which is equivalent to the `NetworkNamespacePath=` setting documented in [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). It can only assign containers and units to a network namespace that already exists. Because a process can only be in one namespace, `--network-namespace-path` is incompatible with options like `--private-network` which create an anonymous network namespace and isolate the container in it.

It seems that [systemd will get a `Namespace=` setting](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/14915) in some future release of systemd after v246 (v245 was released in March 2020). This will allow units to create their own named network namespaces, rather than being assigned to an existing namespace with `NetworkNamespacePath=` or creating a new anonymous namespace with `PrivateNetwork=`. When this feature is merged, it would make sense for `Namespace=%i` to be added to the `systemd-nspawn@.service` template, so that containers' network namespaces are named by default.